# unzip cannot find or open the tgz file

Tags: command-line, unzip

When I run

```
~$ unzip android-sdk_r24.0.2-linux.tgz
```

I get the error message

```
unzip:  cannot find or open android-sdk_r24.0.2-linux.tgz, 
  android-sdk_r24.0.2-linux.tgz.zip or android-sdk_r24.0.2-linux.tgz.ZIP.
```

Why is this and what can I do to solve this problem?